# How to incorporate recursive VIF elimination into scikit-learn's pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to implement a custom pipeline into the `pipeline` object of `scikit-learn`. The pipeline is to recursively eliminate features using VIF. I referenced to the codes [here](https://www.kaggle.com/ffisegydd/sklearn-multicollinearity-class)

```py
class ReduceVIF(base.BaseEstimator, base.TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, thresh=10.0):
        # From looking at documentation, values between 5 and 10 are "okay".
        # Above 10 is too high and so should be removed.
        self.thresh = thresh
        
        self.scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()


    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        X_copy = X.copy()
        print("ReduceVIF fit")
        if hasattr(self, 'scaler'):
            X = self.scaler.fit(X)
        X = ReduceVIF.calculate_vif(X, self.thresh)
        print(X)
        self.predictors = X.columns
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        print("ReduceVIF transform")
        columns = self.predictors
        if hasattr(self, 'scaler'):
            X = pd.DataFrame(self.scaler.transform(X), columns=columns)
        return X
        # return ReduceVIF.calculate_vif(X, self.thresh)

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_vif(X, thresh=10.0):
        # Taken from https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/253620/53565 and modified
        dropped = True
        count = 0
        while dropped and count <= 15:
            
            print(count)
            variables = X.columns

            dropped = False
            
            
            vif = [
                variance_inflation_factor(X[variables].values, X.columns.get_loc(var))
                for var in X.columns
            ]

            max_vif = max(vif)
            if max_vif > thresh:
                maxloc = vif.index(max_vif)
                print(f"Dropping {X.columns[maxloc]} with vif={max_vif}")
                X = X.drop([X.columns.tolist()[maxloc]], axis=1)
                dropped = True
                count +=1
            print(X.shape)
            
        return X
```

---

and I tried to call/make a pipeline as such

```py
# create a feature preparation pipeline for a model
def make_finetuning_pipeline(model):
    steps = list()
    # standardization
    #steps.append(('standardize', preprocessing.StandardScaler()))
    steps.append(('remove_multicollinearity', ReduceVIF(thresh=10)))
    #steps.append(("feature_selection", feature_selection.RFE(linear_model.LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', solver='liblinear'))))
    # the model
    steps.append(('model', model))
    # create pipeline
    _pipeline = pipeline.Pipeline(steps=steps)
    return _pipeline
```

But somehow it is not working and the error is either each fold has different columns, or there is an attribute error. Does anyone know how to incoprorate VIF into a scikit learn pipeline?

Here is my snippet of code in github gist for reproducibility. [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/ghnreigns/7458a9f47985e3b13faa9a32d81a5c16#file-vifpipeline-py)

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my own question: I have spent half a day trying to debug, a preliminary version that works is as follows, not elegant, but for now it is working as expected.

```
class ReduceVIF(base.BaseEstimator, base.TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, thresh=10):
        # From looking at documentation, values between 5 and 10 are "okay".
        # Above 10 is too high and so should be removed.
        self.thresh = thresh
        self.predictor_cols = [
            "radius_mean",
            "texture_mean",
            "perimeter_mean",
            "area_mean",
            "smoothness_mean",
            "compactness_mean",
            "concavity_mean",
            "concave points_mean",
            "symmetry_mean",
            "fractal_dimension_mean",
            "radius_se",
            "texture_se",
            "perimeter_se",
            "area_se",
            "smoothness_se",
            "compactness_se",
            "concavity_se",
            "concave points_se",
            "symmetry_se",
            "fractal_dimension_se",
            "radius_worst",
            "texture_worst",
            "perimeter_worst",
            "area_worst",
            "smoothness_worst",
            "compactness_worst",
            "concavity_worst",
            "concave points_worst",
            "symmetry_worst",
            "fractal_dimension_worst",
        ]

    def reset(self):

        self.predictor_cols = [
            "radius_mean",
            "texture_mean",
            "perimeter_mean",
            "area_mean",
            "smoothness_mean",
            "compactness_mean",
            "concavity_mean",
            "concave points_mean",
            "symmetry_mean",
            "fractal_dimension_mean",
            "radius_se",
            "texture_se",
            "perimeter_se",
            "area_se",
            "smoothness_se",
            "compactness_se",
            "concavity_se",
            "concave points_se",
            "symmetry_se",
            "fractal_dimension_se",
            "radius_worst",
            "texture_worst",
            "perimeter_worst",
            "area_worst",
            "smoothness_worst",
            "compactness_worst",
            "concavity_worst",
            "concave points_worst",
            "symmetry_worst",
            "fractal_dimension_worst",
        ]

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print("ReduceVIF fit")
        tmp, self.predictor_cols = ReduceVIF.calculate_vif(X, self.predictor_cols, self.thresh)
        col_index = [self.predictor_cols.index(col_name) for col_name in self.predictor_cols]
        self.col_index = col_index
        print("tmp", self.col_index)
        self.reset()
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        print("ReduceVIF transform")
        # columns = X.columns.tolist()
        # print(X.shape)
        return X[:, self.col_index]

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_vif(X, columns, thresh=10.0):
        # Taken from https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/253620/53565 and modified
        dropped = True
        count = 0
        while dropped and count <= 15:
            column_index = X.shape[1]
            predictor_cols = np.arange(X.shape[1])
            dropped = False
            print(count)

            vif = []
            for var in range(column_index):
                # print(predictor_cols.shape)
                vif.append(variance_inflation_factor(X[:, predictor_cols], var))

            max_vif = max(vif)
            if max_vif > thresh:
                maxloc = vif.index(max_vif)
                print(f"Dropping {maxloc} with vif={max_vif}")
                # X = X.drop([X.columns.tolist()[maxloc]], axis=1)
                X = np.delete(X, maxloc, axis=1)
                columns.pop(maxloc)
                dropped = True
                count += 1
        return X, columns
```